# Javascript alert message tabs out of IE11 and into something else that is maximized

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, internet-explorer-11, alert

This is only happening in IE11 (not Firefox)

Use case: User is attempting to enter something into a validated field. If they enter something incorrect, an alert pops up and focuses back in on the field.

Problem: When the alert message pops up in IE11, it directs to another window. For instance, if Notepad++ is open behind IE, it'll show Notepad++ with the alert, then once the alert is closed, the IE window reopens and the field is focused. If I comment out the alert, this redirect of windows does not happen. This does not happen in Firefox.

I have the following code  (note "input", "validationMethodCall", and "fieldId" are placeholders for what I have, not the actual code.):

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {   
    if(validationMethodCall($(this).val())) {       
    } else {
        alert("Alert message");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(fieldId).focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like something must have redefined `window.alert()` in your environment. This isn't normal behavior of `alert()`.

Comment: We are not able to produce the issue with the above code sample. I suggest you try to create a sample based on your actual code which can produce the issue with the IE 11 browser. It can help us to understand the issue properly and we can try to provide suggestions for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I got same isssue. I think this is IE11 bug